# How can I set up a realistic looking (monitor) screen shader that does NOT react to light by changing its brightness?

Tags: shaders, hdri

In my scene, I show a computer monitor. This computer monitor shows an image.

I would like to know how I can set a material shader that looks realistic.

In my scene, I also have lights, and the lights affect the screen image in such a way that it (in my opinion) treats the image like a real object.

But I think a real monitor screen would react by strong reflections, but not by making anything brighter or dark, right?

[image]

This is the background image's material shader:

[image]

Edit:
Here is what it looks like for me with the suggested glossy shader. But it doesn't look as I expected it:

[image]

I hope I did it correctly. I am using multiple images as a background image (I switch between them during the animation of the video), so my shader looks a bit complicated. I hope I did it correctly:

[image]

Because I didn't know how to post a screenshot of this huge node shader, I have uploaded the updated blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQlwpd1dCRBcbhoeHpOr_Oobn_18VhAs/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like this for the monitor screen material - the Emission of the image makes it glow slightly like a real screen, and the Glossy Shader gives the desired level of reflection (based on the roughness value). You can also change the value of the mix shader - closer to 1 = more glassy, tinted screen - more towards 0 = brigher, more "glowy" screen:

[image: EmitMonitor]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that, but it doesn't look as I expected. I have added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain in a bit more detail what you find incorrect about the look of the screen/reflections (in your own example), and what your desired outcome is? Do you want it more or less reflective? Also - I see you have many lights nearby, do you want their "bulb spots" to be visible?

Comment: Thank you, but this is much too much. The effect should look very very subtle. I would like the screen to have almost no reflection at all, like a very good computer screen, but it should still be glossy so that the image colors are not "damped" like in a screen that was made a bit rough in order to avoid ANY reflections.

Comment: During the animation, the device is turned around and shown from different angles, and if there is NO reflection at all, it might not look right, I guess.

Comment: Maybe something more like this then - this is a more extreme example of "no reflection" - the key features are the high roughness and the low _Specular_ (which the Principled BSDF provides), in addition to the emission. You may want to increase the specular to something like .1 and lower the roughness to .6 or something to fit your specific needs - https://ibb.co/5h81DCr

Comment: A modern screen is quite litterally a bunch of white lights filtered out to take colors, and with a somewhat matte sheet on top. So you definitely want emission and some form of reflection. If you really want to use the Principled Shader, you WILL have a washed out result because of how the principled shader implements reflections and Fresnel. The simplest way to do it is just an Emission shader slightly mixed with a Glossy shader that has a bit of roughness. https://i.imgur.com/axwGRV5.jpeg

Comment: The Mix shader will controll how much of gloss you want, while the Glossy shader's roughness acts like a reflection blur https://i.imgur.com/axwGRV5.jpeg